How can I include an clickable button in a tooltip of a TreeItem in TreeView?
tooltip image
I am using the tooltip property of TreeItem to show some information when hovering a tree item in a tree view. Now I want to include some operations in it, such as click the external-link icon just like it is a button. I also want to include more style of the content in the tooltip.
But, when I move my mouse to the tooltip, it just disappears because my mouse is not hovering the original tree item any more.
I want to know how to keep the tooltip when I move my mouse onto it, and how to customize the style of the content in a tooltip? Thank you!
